# How to dynamically inject a mixin into component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that requires a mixin depending on the props it receives.

```js
const timerMixin = {
    created() {
        console.log("Timer mixin injected")
    }
}

export default {
    name: 'Component A',
    props: ['hasTimer'],
    mixins: this.hasTimer ? [timerMixin] : [] // fails because `this` is not available here 
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically  inject a mixin into the component?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't going to be able to do this and it's actually by design, not accident, as stated by Evan You in [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2897):

> I don't like the idea of runtime mixins, because it makes your components' behavior unpredictable depending on when mixins are applied.

This means that you can't assign a `mixin` after the fact and there is not any way to get the `this` context before the `mixin` loads.

I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming to do here, but if you simply don't want to  init the timer mixin, then you can do the check in the mixins created hook before you take any further action (I personally would also add the `hasTimer` prop to the mixin aswell, but I'll keep it how you had it), so you get:

```
var timerMixin = {
  created(){
    if(this.hasTimer){
      this.initTimer();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initTimer(){
      console.log('Init Timer Mixin')
    }
  }
}


export default {
    mixins: [timerMixin],
    props: ['hasTimer']
  });
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gnkha6hr/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way, currently, to dynamically add or remove mixins for a component. The `this` var is not available at that scope. And in the earliest [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), `beforeCreate`, mixins are already loaded.

In your case, depending on what's in the `timerMixin` mixin, it might make sense to make a separate timer component with related logic which could be loaded dynamically in the template of `Component A`.

Otherwise, always loading the mixin probably wouldn't be too bad (performance-wise), since the data will be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way you can try

```
import myMixin from './views/mixin.js';
import component'./views/component.vue';


const _component = { ...component, };
_component .mixins = [myMixin];


export const router = [

  {
    path: '/path1', //
    name: 'path1',
    component: component,
  },


  {
    path: '/path2', //
    name: 'path2',
    component: _component ,
  }

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this ... if you are willing to place a 'setup' component in front of the component where you need to have the dynamic mixin.

Loosely, it involves pre-formulating the child component in that setup component by creating a new Vue component that includes a mixin containing both the base component you need to extend and the mixin that you want it extended by

Here is what that setup component might look like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MixinA from 'mixins/a'
import MixinB from 'mixins/b'
import BaseComponent from './base.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    view: {
      //we'll store our dynamically created component prototype here
      component: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    //- use some logic to choose a mixin - I'll just return mixinA from a computed property, but it could be from a function call or something else
    whichMixin () {
      return MixinA
    }
  },
  
  // when the setup component is created, create the dynamically mixed-in component
  created () { 
    this.setup()
  },

  methods: {
    setup () {
      //- this is our dynamic mixin
      const { whichMixin } = this
      //- use it to extend the component we needed extended
      const prototype = { mixins: [ BaseComponent, whichMixin ] }
      //- set it as a property so we can access it in our template
      this.view.component = new Vue(prototype)
    }
  }
}

//- in our template, use it dynamically
//- template (lang = pug)
div(v-cloak)
  component(:is='view.component')
```

If you need to `$watch` a condition (ie in case the component needs to change in response to a trigger that can't be computed in `whichMixin`, then you can setup a watcher and call `setup()` from that watcher

NOTE: no need to manually `$destroy` the component to prevent memory leaks. The prototype mounted in view.component is not instantiated - its basically the extneded POJO - and the dynamically included one in the template will be destroyed as part of Vue's standard component clean up operation during its lifecycle

Comment: PS - I should stress that this works with 2.x - the merge strategy for data() functions in Vue 3 isn't the same - anything returned from the last data() call replaces the data object instead of merges it .... bummer....